# Переход между ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, navigationcontroller, uiviewcontroller, uitabbar

У меня такой вопрос.
Есть TabBarController с несколькими вкладками. У первой вкладки есть еще свои ViewControllers. Мне нужно осуществить переход (как на картинке стрелка, с ячейки) с сохранением отображения NavigationBar и TabBar.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 Я пробовал использовать метод:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "мой идентификатор", sender: nil)
```

НО при таком переходе отображается ViewControllers без NavBar и TabBar. Как можно это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
```

По поводу `NavigationBar`, если вы не создадите `UINavigationController` то нативного `NavigationBar` не будет (но его можно создать как обычный `UIView` или добавить `UINavigationController`)

Comment: Спасибо сделал. Помогло. ДА я добавил NavigationController.  Все так как я и хочу).

Answer (score 0):

либо:

```
 let windows = UIApplication.shared.windows
        for window in windows {
            if let tabBar = window.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
                tabBar.selectedIndex = 1
            }
        }
    }
```

либо:

```
tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
```